# Stuck while making a quiz app in Android studio using JSON and Jackson API

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I'm trying to make a quiz app in android studio in java, using JSON and the Jackson API to convert the request.

The following is the xml of my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionField"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Question"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/choice1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="1"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/choice1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/choice1"
        android:text="2"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/choice1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/choice1"
        android:text="3"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/choice4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/choice2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/choice2"
        android:text="4"
        />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Then I have the class for the Questions and for the Response:

```
package com.example.triviaquiz.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Questions implements Serializable {

    private String category, difficulty, question, correct_answer;
    private List <String> incorrect_answers;

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    public void setDifficulty(String difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getCorrect_answer() {
        return correct_answer;
    }

    public void setCorrect_answer(String correct_answer) {
        this.correct_answer = correct_answer;
    }

    public List<String> getIncorrect_answers() {
        return incorrect_answers;
    }

    public void setIncorrect_answers(List<String> incorrect_answers) {
        this.incorrect_answers = incorrect_answers;
    }
}
```

```
package com.example.triviaquiz.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

public class Questions implements Serializable {

    private String category, difficulty, question, correct_answer;
    private List <String> incorrect_answers;

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getDifficulty() {
        return difficulty;
    }

    public void setDifficulty(String difficulty) {
        this.difficulty = difficulty;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public String getCorrect_answer() {
        return correct_answer;
    }

    public void setCorrect_answer(String correct_answer) {
        this.correct_answer = correct_answer;
    }

    public List<String> getIncorrect_answers() {
        return incorrect_answers;
    }

    public void setIncorrect_answers(List<String> incorrect_answers) {
        this.incorrect_answers = incorrect_answers;
    }
}
```

Lastly, this is the MainActivity:

```
package com.example.triviaquiz;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.triviaquiz.model.Questions;
import com.example.triviaquiz.model.ResponseQuiz;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button choice1, choice2, choice3, choice4;
    TextView question;
    List<Questions> questionsList;
    int indexQuestion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        question = findViewById(R.id.questionField);
        choice1 = findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        choice2 = findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        choice3 = findViewById(R.id.choice3);
        choice4 = findViewById(R.id.choice4);

        loadQuestions();
    }

    public void loadQuestions(){
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://opentdb.com/api.php?amount=10&type=multiple")
                .get()
                .build();
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull IOException e) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layoutMain), "Request failed", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call call, @NonNull Response response) throws IOException {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layoutMain), "Response successful", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String body = response.body().string();
                    ResponseQuiz resp = mapper.readValue(body, ResponseQuiz.class);
                    questionsList = resp.getResults();
                    indexQuestion = 0;
                    //Collections.shuffle(questionsList);
                    runOnUiThread(() -> {
                                showQuestions(indexQuestion);
                            });
                }
                else{
                    Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.layoutMain), "Response not successful", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void showQuestions(int index){
            Questions currentQuestion = questionsList.get(index);
            question.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestion());
            List<String> answers = currentQuestion.getIncorrect_answers();
            answers.add(currentQuestion.getCorrect_answer());
            Collections.shuffle(answers);
            choice1.setText(answers.get(0));
            choice2.setText(answers.get(1));
            choice3.setText(answers.get(2));
            choice4.setText(answers.get(3));
    }
}
```

When I launch the app, nothing from the questions and relative answers in the url gets set in the textview for the question and in the buttons for the answers as I thought it would and I don't get why.

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).